# Configuring Django static folder for python anywhere

Tags: python, django

I am new in Django, previously I had a test site in which my static files were placed in static folders. There was a static folder for every app. But now I want to make a site, which will be deployed to python anywhere and so I have to have only one static folder.

This is the project folder: https://github.com/martin-varbanov96/fmi-fall-2016/tree/master/django/click_bait/miranda

You can see that in the settings file I have:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

in my target html file I have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'home/css/style.css' %}" type="text/css">
```

which returns 404.

What is wrong how should I arrage my folders so that they are best working for the pythonanywhere host?

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting a 404 error you should ensure debugging mode is on. If I assume it is on (as it is in the `settings.py` you have on GitHub), then your web server just isn't serving the static files. I would ensure you've run `python manage.py collectstatic` which will push the static files for the project to the static folder you've defined in `settings.py`.

I would also ensure that you've configured Python Anywhere to serve these files. According to their website (source: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles/) you should ensure you have that static folder added so their server knows to serve the files. The steps at that link are as follows:

- Go to the Web tab on the PythonAnywhere dashboard
- Go to the Static Files section
- Enter the same URL as STATIC_URL in the url section (typically, /static/)
- Enter the path from STATIC_ROOT into the path section (the full path, including /home/username/etc)

Comment: well, when I put the static folder directly in my app, the css is working